# Spiral Permutation Sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, permutations

We can roll up the natural numbers in a rectangular spiral:

```
 17--16--15--14--13
  |               |
 18   5---4---3  12
  |   |       |   |
 19   6   1---2  11
  |   |           |
 20   7---8---9--10
  |
 21--22--23--24--25
```

But now that we have them on a rectangular grid we can unwind the spiral in a different order, e.g. going clockwise, starting north:

```
 17  16--15--14--13
  |   |           |
 18   5   4---3  12
  |   |   |   |   |
 19   6   1   2  11
  |   |       |   |
 20   7---8---9  10
  |               |
 21--22--23--24--25
```

The resulting sequence is clearly a permutation of the natural numbers:

```
1, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, ...
```

Your task is to compute this sequence. ([OEIS A020703](https://oeis.org/A020703), but spoiler warning: it contains another interesting definition and several formulae that you might want to figure out yourself.)

**Fun fact:** all 8 possible unwinding orders have their own OEIS entry.

### The Challenge

Given a positive integer `n`, return the `n`th element of the above sequence.

You may write a program or function, taking input via STDIN (or closest alternative), command-line argument or function argument and outputting the result via STDOUT (or closest alternative), function return value or function (out) parameter.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

### Test Cases

```
1       1
2       4
3       3
4       2
5       9
6       8
7       7
8       6
9       5
100     82
111     111
633     669
1000    986
5000    4942
9802    10000
10000   9802
```

For a complete list up to and including `n = 11131` [see the b-file on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A020703/b020703.txt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
’Æ½ð²+ḷ‘Ḥ_
```

Another Jelly answer on my phone.

```
’Æ½ð²+ḷ‘Ḥ_   A monadic hook:
’Æ½          Helper link. Input: n
’             n-1
 Æ½            Atop integer square root. Call this m.
   ð         Start a new dyadic link. Inputs: m, n
    ²+ḷ‘Ḥ_    Main link:
    ²+ḷ       Square m, add it to itself,
       ‘      and add one.
        Ḥ     Double the result
         _    and subtract n.
```

Try it [here](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZw4bCvcOwwrIr4bi34bikKzJf&input=&args=MTAw).

Comment: Any tips on getting started with Jelly? I can't tell how the forks/hooks get parsed at all.

Comment: Learn APL or J first. Chains are actually easier than trains because the functions all have fixed arity.

Comment: I see. Yeah, I have J experience. I suppose I will try to read `jelly.py` and figure out which chains are supported.

Comment: How the hell did you type that on your phone!? That's more impressive than the code itself is!

Answer (score 8):

## Japt, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
V=U¬c)²-V *2-U+2
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=MStVrGMgsi0oVS0oVawtMSBjILI=&input=MTAwMDA=)

Based on the observation that

> F(N) = ceil(N^.5) * (ceil(N^.5)-1) - N + 2

Or, rather, that

> F(N) = the first square greater than or equal to N, minus its square root, minus N, plus 2.

I don't know if this explanation is on the OEIS page, as I haven't looked at it yet.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, 28 bytes

```
n->2((m=isqrt(n-1))^2+m+1)-n
```

This is a lambda function that accepts an integer and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable.

We define *m* to be the largest integer such that *m*<sup>2</sup> ≤ *n*-1, i.e. the integer square root of *n*-1 (`isqrt`). We can then simplify the OEIS expression 2 (*m* + 1) *m* - *n* + 2 down to simply 2 (*m*<sup>2</sup> + *m* + 1) - *n*.

[Try it online](http://goo.gl/rwF4hG)

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 14 bytes

```
qi_(mQ7Ybb2*\-
```

Using Alex's approach: `2*(m^2+m+1)-n` where `m = isqrt(n-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

### ES7, <s>31</s> <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
n=>(m=--n**.5|0)*++m*2-~-n
```

I had independently discovered Alex's formula but I can't prove it because I wasn't near a computer at the time.

Edit: Saved 3 bytes partly thanks to @ETHproductions. Saved a further 2 bytes.

Comment: `n=>((m=--n**.5|0)+m*m)*2-n+1` would work, I think.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks, I was wondering to myself how to get that `--n` in there...

Comment: @ETHproductions Heh, I managed to shave 2 bytes from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>25</s> <s>19</s> 14 bytes

```apl
{2⊥⍨3⍴⌊√⍵-1}-⊢
```

-6 bytes from Adám.

-5 bytes from Bubbler.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qHeuQqJGnqatkZZGWk5@fpFGcWFRiUaerqGmprahpha6mG6ettH/aqNHXUsf9a4wftS75VFP16OOWY96t@oa1uo@6lr0P@1R24RHvX2Pupof9a4BKji03vhR28RHfVODg5yBZIiHZ/D/NAVDrjQFIyA2BmITIDYFYjMQbWBgAKQsLQxAsoZAngEA)

A direct implementation of the last function mentioned on the OEIS page:

\$a(n)=2×\Big(\big\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\big\rfloor+1\Big)×\big\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\big\rfloor-n+2\$

### Explanation:

```apl
{(2-⍵)+2×(1+⌊√⍵-1)×⌊√⍵-1} ⍵ → n
                   ⌊√⍵-1  floor of root of n-1
         (1+⌊√⍵-1)×       times 1 + floor of root of n-1
       2×                 times 2
 (2-⍵)                    plus 2-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qHeuQqJGnqatkZZGWk5@fpFGcWFRiUaerqGmprahpha6mG6ettH/ag0j3Ue9WzW1jQ5P1zDUftTT9ahjFlAAqODwdCRe7f@0R20THvX2PepqftS75lHvlkPrjR@1TXzUNzU4yBlIhnh4Bv9PUzDkSlMwAmJjIDYBYlMgNgNiQwMgAAA)

Comment: If you remove the redundant parentheses (remember APL's long right-scope, a.k.a. "right-to-left" rule), you may find that you've not translated the formula right.

Comment: yup, it was wrong. I think this solution works correctly. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: [19](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qHeuQqJGnqatkZZGWk5@fpFGcWFRiUaerqGmprahpha6mG6ettH/aiPdR71bdY0OTzfU0D48/VHXIs1HPV2POmaBRA1r/6c9apvwqLfvUVfzo941j3q3HFpv/Kht4qO@qcFBzkAyxMMz@H@agiFXmoIREBsDsQkQmwKxGRAbGgABAA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online"): `{2-⍵-2×1(+×⊢)⌊√⍵-1}`

Comment: I think `{2⊥⍨3⍴⌊√⍵-1}-⊢` should work?

Comment: Yup it does. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qHeuQqJGnqatkZZGWk5@fpFGcWFRiUaerqGmprahpha6mG6ettH/aqNHXUsf9a4wftS75VFP16OOWY96t@oa1uo@6lr0P@1R24RHvX2Pupof9a4BKji03vhR28RHfVODg5yBZIiHZ/D/NAVDrjQFIyA2BmITIDYFYjMQbWBgAKQsLQxAsoZAngEA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Comment: Explaining the 14-byte solution is left as an exercise to the reader. :P

Comment: I am almost as confused as the readers at this point

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 21 bytes

```
K2-h+^.E@QKK^t.E@QKKQ
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K2-h%2B%5E.E%40QKK%5Et.E%40QKKQ&input=8&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A100%0A111%0A633%0A1000%0A5000%0A9802%0A10000&debug=0)

Nothing fancy going on. Same method as in the JAPT answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
qX^Y[tQ*Q2*G-
```

Based on [Lynn's CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70805/36398).

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cVhea3RRKlEyKkct&input=MTAw) (`Y[` has been replaced by `k` according to changes in the language)

```
q       % input n. Subtract 1
X^      % square root
Y[      % floor
tQ      % duplicate and add 1
*       % multiply
Q       % add 1
2*      % multiply by 2
G-      % subtract n
```

---

This uses a different approach than other answers (**16 bytes**):

```
6Y3iQG2\+YLt!G=)
```

It explicitly generates the two spiral matrices (actually, vertically flipped versions of them, but that doesn't affect the output). The first one is

```
17    16    15    14    13
18     5     4     3    12
19     6     1     2    11
20     7     8     9    10
21    22    23    24    25
```

and the second one traces the modified path:

```
25    10    11    12    13
24     9     2     3    14
23     8     1     4    15
22     7     6     5    16
21    20    19    18    17
```

To find the `n`-th number of the sequence it suffices to find `n` in the second matrix and pick the corresponding number in the first. The matrices need to be big enough so that `n` appears, and should have *odd* size so that the origin (number `1`) is in the same position in both.

**[Try it online](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UUcyXCsgNlkzWUx0IUc9KQ&input=MTAw)** too! (`6Y3` has been moved according to changes in the language)

```
6Y3      % 'spiral' string
i        % input n
QG2\+    % round up to an odd number large enough
YL       % generate spiral matrix of that size: first matrix
t!       % duplicate and transpose: second matrix
G=       % logical index that locates n in the second matrix
)        % use that index into first matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 20 bytes

```
-1$r$[I*I+I+1=*2-?=.
```

This uses the same technique as pretty much all other answers.

#### Explanation

```
-1                   § Build the expression Input - 1
  $r                 § Square root of Input - 1
    $[I              § Unify I with the floor of this square root
       *I+I+1        § Build the expression I * I + I + 1
             =*2-?   § Evaluate the previous expression (say, M) and build the expression
                     § M * 2 - Input
                  =. § Unify the output with the evaluation of M * 2 - Input
```

A midly interesting fact about this answer is that it is easier and shorter to use `=` rather than parentheses.